# How can I install Windows 7 to a HDD in a caddy from within Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, installation

Is it possible to connect an internal drive (e.g. SATA 2.5") to a USB caddy and install Windows 7 to that drive (from within Windows 7) such that it can be removed from the caddy, connected via SATA to a PC, and booted off of?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not trivially.

1. Connect the the to your host using a caddy with eSATA.
2. Then install virtualisation software. (e.g. virtual PC)
3. Use the PC as a raw disk in the VM.
4. Boot the VM and install windows.
5. Run sysprep.
6. Move the now installed disk to a PC with similar or identical hardware.

All in all it might be much simpler if you tell use why you want to do this.

E.g. "I have two identical PCs, but in one the CDROM is broken" (In which case I would suggest removing the original drive from the working PC. Inserting the new drive and installing windows. Then moving the drives to their final PCs).

Also note that sysprep should not be skipped when there are HW differences.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was merely curious. I have the option of installing via disc, but the HDD is already out and in the caddy (it belongs in a laptop which crashed).
The PCs are different, but both Win7 x64 (different editions, however).
It may turn out that the VM route is easier, as I have acquired the drivers & ISO on the host machine, but it does not have a ODD. I would need to use my OSX laptop to burn the ISO, reinstall the HDD into the laptop, reinstall Windows, transfer the drivers etc. I will give it a shot! Thanks again.

Comment: No need to burn an iso. You can Also [write the iso to an USB pendrive](http://wudt.codeplex.com/) and use that to install from. That is a lot quicker and it does not need a CD-R. Maybe you can even mount the iso directly (that is how I do it with Vmware workstation, but that presents emulated hardware to the OS).

Answer (score -1):

I hate telling people that Google is their friend, but it is; a quick search yielded this: http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7-to-usb-external-hard-drive-must-read/

Let us know it it's any good.

**Addendum:** This might also be of use: http://bootableusb.net/make-bootable-external-hdd-install-windows-78/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I saw a few of these but they all seem oriented towards drives that will remain USB drives. I thought the process might be different for drives that will end up SATA again.

Comment: Well, I guess you might be right on that one.